# Selenium WebDriver NoSuchElementException for a checkbox

Tags: java, selenium

The thing is my test works great when i run it(by the way, its based on IE8), but when its run from Bamboo, it doesn't find an element, even though its not hidden and it is there on the page.
I use this to get the elements:

```
public WebElement getElementWhenVisible(By locator, int timeout) {
        WebElement element = null;
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
        log.info("Getting element with locator {}", locator);
        element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
        return element;
    }
```

My element is just a simple checkbox in a table. Every time in normal conditions it finds it, but for a strange reason on the Bamboo it doesnt find it
The windows is XP and driver version 2.37, .I  think

 My question is, is there a way I can force retrieve the element or tell the webdriver to refresh the table that contains the element?

Answer (score 0):

You could try finding the element with Javascript instead.

```
WebElement element = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('myCheckbox')");
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(>someid>)));
```